# React native box shadow solution for images

Tags: android, ios, css, reactjs, react-native

I am trying to add styling to different images based upon their touched status. I am struggling to find a solution that works for both android and ios that adds a border shadow to the images. On web I used box-shadow to do this, but that option doesnt work on RN. So far I have tried elevation (not sure if I'm using this correctly as it doesn't seem to do much?) and shadowColor but neither is doing what I need it to

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { TouchableWithoutFeedback, Image, Alert } from 'react-native';
import { View, Text } from 'native-base';

class Answer extends Component {

  render() {
    const { option, onClickCallback, isSelected, isBlurred } = this.props;

    const {
      cssUnSelected,
      cssSelected,
      cssBlurred,
      image
    } = styles;
    let mode = 'contain';

    let cssSelection = cssUnSelected;
    if (isSelected) {
      cssSelection = cssSelected;
    }
    if (isBlurred) {
      cssSelection = cssBlurred;
    }

    return (
      <View style={cssSelection}>
        <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={onClickCallback}>
          <Image source={require('../../assets/imgs/draw90.png')}
            resizeMode={mode}
            style={image} />
        </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
      </View>
    )
  }
}

const styles = {
  cssSelected: {
    borderRadius: 100,
    elevation: 90,
    shadowColor: "green"
  },
  cssUnSelected: {
    borderRadius: 100,
    elevation: 90,
    shadowColor: "blue"
  },
  cssBlurred: {
    elevation: 10,
    borderRadius: 100,
    opacity: 0.5,
    shadowColor: "red"
  },
  image: {
    flex: 1,
    marginLeft: "1%",
    marginRight: "1%",
    maxWidth: 90
  }
}

export default Answer;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing few things like **backgroundColor** for the view which is required for shadows to show for various reasons. Moreover you need to provide other shadow style props like **shadowOffset**, **shadowRadius** other than shadow color for rendering shadows in **IOS** (because default values could be 0 or null or anything).

For **Android** sadly you don't have any customization as of react-native **v0.45**, you can only provide **elevation** style prop which adds drop shadow at the bottom of the view for android version **lollipop** and above (you can't provide offset, shadow color or radius etc).

Below is an small working example

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, StyleSheet,Platform,Button } from 'react-native';

export default class App extends Component {
  state = {
    isSelected: false
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <View style={this.state.isSelected ? styles.boxSelected : styles.boxUnselected} ></View>
        <Button title='toggle select' onPress={() => this.setState({isSelected: !this.state.isSelected}) } />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#ecf0f1',
  },
  boxSelected: {
    width:100,
    height:100,
    backgroundColor:'blue',
    borderRadius:10,
    ...Platform.select({
      ios: {
        shadowColor: 'rgba(0,0,0, .7)',
        shadowOffset: { height:0, width: 0 },
        shadowOpacity: 1,
        shadowRadius: 5,
      },
      android: {
        elevation: 5
      },
    }),
  },
  boxUnselected: {
    width:100,
    height:100,
    backgroundColor:'blue',
    borderRadius:10,
  }
});
```

snack demo - https://snack.expo.io/r1fcX6_vb

Hope you get an idea...

Comment: Thanks for your answer Ravi. So the design that I'm trying to build has different coloured shadows based on their touch state. Looks like I may have to go back to design on this one!

Answer (score 1):

Just wrap your `<Image>` Component inside a `<View>` Component.
and style the `<View>` Instead of `<Image>`